# create Dialog over another dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I want to create a dialog.  I create a class and class extend `Dialog`. I create an object from this class when click on a button from my activity and call show method. If i click on button 2 times or more, second dialog create over first dialog and third dialog create over second dialog and more. when i click on back button , my dialogs remove one by one. How can i solve this problem? Please say a recommend. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialog has a function  named `isShowing()` which returns a boolean to indicate that your Dialog Show status , when your button pressed you can check that if previous Dialog isShowing(), don't instantiate it again .

Comment: Thanks this is work good, but i create instance from dialog in switch case and on this, the app create new instance from my dialog and showing is false, if i create dialog out of switch case, showing works. Can i use showing but can't create instance out of switch case?

Comment: ty for accept , if i get you right , you can create a global Varibale of Dialog like : Dialog dialog at the top of class , then instantiate it wherever you want, and you can access that obeject in whole class and check isShowing.

Comment: I used this, but this way get more memory from create on fire click and in switch case? how much use memory create top of class than create on fire event? Thanks a lot

Comment: @user3209380 : unfortunately i don't have any clue about that ;)